# Custom Post Type issue - Portfolio

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have set up a custom post type for a Portfolio, with its own taxonomy.

The permalink structure is as follows:

- Portfolio list `/portfolio/`
- Portfolio category list `/portfolio/category/`
- Portfolio item `/portfolio/portfolio-item/`

These work as expected, except for the single post page (portfolio item). This currently returns a 404 page.

I am loading in this order:

```
add_action( 'init', 'portfolioCategoryTaxonomy', 0 ); // taxonomy 

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_portfolio', 1 ); // post type
```

If I change the load order around (so taxonomy 1 and post type 0), the single page works and all of the others break.

The permalink rewrites are as follows:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '' , 'with_front' => false ), //taxonomy

'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio','with_front' => false) // post type
```

My thoughts were that it was something to do with the rewrites for the permalinks, but I'm not sure how I can diagnose the issue.

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After creating a new Custom post type, you have to save permalink in wordpress dashboard.

Go to Settings -> Permalinks and Click Save Changes. It will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried doing this, and it doesn't fix the issue.
Not sure if it makes a difference, but I have a custom structure set up for the standard blog posts, like so:
`/blog/%postname%/`

Comment: Have you tried using default permalink i.e. plain? Check if that works.
If that works, issue is with your custom structure.